# Maven : How to use Maven for generating Spring and CXF Support Application

Tags: maven-2

I need to create a Simple web Application with Spring and CXF Setup

I am using apache-maven-3.0.3 Support for this.

Please tell me what me what number to enter in mvn command prompt , to generate those required artifacts for this.

I tried this way , it only generated the Java Interface and Implementation class

1. HelloWorld  2. HelloWorldImpl

and two xml files inside WEB-INF

1. beans    2. web

**But i don't know why no jar files have been got created.
I tried this way**

```
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case sensitive contains): 135: 116

Define value for property 'groupId': : com
Define value for property 'artifactId': : MyAPP
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package':  com: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com
artifactId: MyAPP
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com
 Y: : y
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: cxf-jaxws-javafirst:2.1.4
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: MyAPP
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: C:\myapp
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: C:\myapp\MyAPP
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:49.062s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 25 16:47:29 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) are convenient, but I don't think they are  going to be helpful to you for this case. [This tutorial](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/maven-run-webapp-by-maven-jetty-plugin/) is a nice, basic example that  outputs a running webapp using Spring and Maven. I would suggest you download the code, have a play around and figure out how it works, then start layering in your CXF functionality.

Go forth and build something awesome!